# Substract years and days to a dataframe

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to subtract two years and and add one day to dates like below.  Using the package lubridate, I am able to subtract dates from regular years or leap years separately, but I need to do both at the same time.

```
df <- data.frame(
ServiceDate = c('2010-02-28','2016-02-29'), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$ServiceDate <- as.Date(df$ServiceDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

library(lubridate)

df$TwoYearsEarlier <- ymd(df$ServiceDate) - years(2) + days(1)
```

This is what i get from the code above

```
df
ServiceDate TwoYearsEarlier
2010-02-28      2008-02-29
2016-02-29            <NA>
```

Is there a way to calc the days for both at the same time?

This is the desired result:

```
df
ServiceDate TwoYearsEarlier
2010-02-28      2008-02-29
2016-02-29      2014-03-01
```

In Excel I use something like this

=DATE(YEAR(AW2)-2,MONTH(AW2),DAY(AW2)+1)

Comment: this functions are vectorized I am wondering why it returns `NA`, it is possibile because is a future data?

Comment: The `years` function is looking for `2014-02-29` and can't find it. Try a workaround `ymd(df$ServiceDate) - days(731)`

Answer (score 3):

use the duration years `dyears`

```
df$TwoYearsEarlier <- ymd(df$ServiceDate) - dyears(2)
df
#  ServiceDate TwoYearsEarlier
#1  2010-02-28      2008-02-29
#2  2016-02-29      2014-03-01
```

Or as I said in the comments, by days:

```
df$TwoYearsEarlier <- df$ServiceDate - days(730)
df
#  ServiceDate TwoYearsEarlier
#1  2010-02-28      2008-02-29
#2  2016-02-29      2014-03-01
```

Comment: Below is the desired output

Comment: I had the output that you first requested, but your request did not reflect your desired output as updated. Both solutions above work.

Answer (score 1):

Years and months are not really well-defined intervals, but it appears you want to use an interval of 2*365 days, which *is* a well-defined duration:

```
> df$TwoYearsEarlier <- ymd(df$ServiceDate) + days(-2*365)
> df
  ServiceDate TwoYearsEarlier
1  2010-02-28      2008-02-29
2  2016-02-29      2014-03-01
```